# Load data into newly added columns in Impala

Tags: hadoop, ddl, impala

Let's say I have a table1 in schema1 like this:

| Stu_ID | Math |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | B+ |

Now, I want to add a new column, for instance, Literature, into table1 in schema1.

```
ALTER TABLE schema1.table 1
ADD COLUMN Literature STRING
```

Table1 now looks like

| Stu_ID | Math | Literature |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | NULL |
| 2 | B | NULL |
| 3 | B+ | NULL |

I want to load data from table2, shema2 based on the respective Stu_ID. Is there a way to do so? I have thought of UPDATE, but Impala only supports updating a kudu table according to my understanding. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

instead of update you can `insert+overwrite`.

```
insert overwrite schema1.table1 t1
select 
t1.stu_id, t1.Math, t2.Literature
from  schema1.table1 t1
join  schema2.table2 t2 ON t1.stu_id=t2.stu_id
```

This will replace whole data of t1 and will replace with old data + new column.